# Redirect to new lightning page be clicking button. Setting parameters to component in new page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, redirect, help, aura-attribute

I have lightning component which I put into lightning page using App Builder. The component display table with field history tracking like in the Salesforce Classic. Also there is a button on component: "Go to all history records". If user clicks it, he must see new lightning page with ONLY my component (and also I must say to component, that it need to display, for example, 1000 records, and to say to it id of sobject, which history user were looked on previous page). All this stuff stored in attribute in component. So, I need to redirect to new page with only my component and set attributes, when user click button on page. I have read about this already:

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
   "url": someurl   
});
urlEvent.fire();
```

But I don`t know, how to set parameters to component in new page. Please, help solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally from winter 17 release you should be able to use the new event [force:navigateToComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm) to achieve the Navigation with passing Ids or other attributes between two components .

For now you can simply pass the parameters via query variables like below

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
 urlEvent.setParams({
   "url": someurl + 'id=xyz' + '&var1=xyz' ;
 });
urlEvent.fire();
```

And then in the destination component you can use window.location.href to fetch the key values .

The JS function in the helper will be like below

```
function getParam(param) {
   var url =   window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i=0;i<url.length;i++) {
      var params = url[i].split("=");
      if(params[0] == param)
       return params[1];
      }
  return false;
 }
```

You will just pass the key and retrieve value from the URL.

Comment: I have try to add simple parameters to url, but my page I want to redirect to has following url:

`https://margaritabarabash-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJvbmU6ZmxleGlwYWdlIiwiYXR0cmlidXRlcyI6eyJ2YWx1ZXMiOnsiZmxleGlQYWdlRGV2ZWxvcGVyTmFtZSI6IkFsbF9GaWVsZF9IaXN0b3J5X1JlY29yZCIsImxhYmVsIjoiQWxsIEZpZWxkIEhpc3RvcnkgUmVjb3JkIiwiaWNvblVybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbWFyZ2FyaXRhYmFyYWJhc2gtZGV2LWVkLm15LnNhbGVzZm9yY2UuY29tL2ltZy9pY29uL3Q0djM1L2N1c3RvbS9jdXN0b20yMV8xMjAucG5nIiwiaWNvbkNvbG9yIjoiOGE3YWVkIn19LCJ0IjoxNDczNjkyNjUxMTk4fQ%3D%3D`
I have got an error

Comment: Sorry i did not get you .If you could elaborate might be able to help you

Comment: What are you trying to do with this base 64 URL ?This seems to be base64 encode string in # paramter

Comment: How you can see, this strange url has # in it and I can not do anything with it. When I added parameters to the end of url, I have got error. Is it more  understandable?

Comment: What does it mean? base64

Comment: I have got this url, added new custom tab with lightning page and added it to navigation menu for my profile. Is there another way to get url of lightning page?

Comment: Whats the issue if you have added as Navigation menu ? Where do you want this URL to reside now ?

Comment: I have added it to Navigation menu only to watch at its url in browser, because I haven't find another way to do it.